# GORM 1-to-many relationship -- 3 tables created rather than 2

Tags: grails, grails-orm, one-to-many

All

My problem is I'm creating a 1-to-many relationship in GORM and expect 2 database tables to be created as backing objects. 3 are created which makes SQL queries overly complex.

I've created a close variant on the 1-to-many in the GORM documentation:

```
class Status {

   List errorMessage

   static hasMany = [errorMessage:ErrorMessage]
}
```

and the error message class:

```
class ErrorMessage {

   String message

   static belongsTo = Status
}
```

I expected this to create two database tables:

```
CREATE TABLE status {
   ID NUMBER(19,0),
   VERSION NUMBER(19,0),
   //other fields
}

CREATE TABLE error_message {
   ID NUMBER(19,0),
   VERSION NUMBER(19,0),
   STATUS_ID NUMBER(19,0),
   MESSAGE VARCHAR(255)
   //other fields
}
```

but actually it wants a third table,

```
CREATE TABLE status_text {
    status_text_id NUMBER(19,0),
    text_idx NUMBER(19,0), 
    text_id NUMBER(19,0)
}
```

Adding Status to the ErrorMessage (a hack as I don't want ErrorMessage to have a reference to Status) class removes the third table but keeps the second foreign key resulting in the Text child object having two foreign key fields.

What I want is simple - just a set of objects attached to the parent will be deleted when it is - any thoughts what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: If you don't want to reference `Status` in `ErrorMessage` (except from `belongsTo`, of course), the JOIN table is needed ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can satisfy both requirements, i.e. that you have cascading deletes and no join table. You need the `belongsTo` to get cascading deletes and that makes the relationship bidirectional. To remove the join table, name the belongsTo with the Map syntax:

```
class ErrorMessage {
   String message
   static belongsTo = [status: Status]
}
```

Comment: I'll give this a go - and respond back. Thank you

Comment: A side note, GORM's effect on creating/expecting a JOIN table (or not) when using the `Map` vs. the `Type` syntax doesn't appear to be documented in the *Grails User Guide* ...

Comment: This has worked. will click the tick. Only minor weirdness is that its required me to add a new db field which appear to reference the child table (or the field within it of the same name). This has the value 0 for every insert. Still - removed the link table. Many thanks.